# "See vote counts" on questions list

Tags: feature-request, vote-count

When viewing a post (and having the privilege to doing it), you can split the score of it into upvotes and downvotes by clicking on the score:

[image: Expanded score]

However, you cannot click question scores when [browsing questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions):

[image: Mouse-over question score]

Could we be able to show upvotes/downvotes when browsing questions (after clicking the score), somewhat like this?

[image: Split votes in browsing]

Comment: Just asking, what additional purpose will it serve? I mean, It's just a click away.

Comment: Not only one click, but one click to open the question, a few seconds to actually load the question, and then the initial click to show the score. @SouravGhosh

Comment: Just for arguments sake, last click does not count, that will be there in your proposed solution also, and time taken != number of click, so my point stands. :)

Comment: It takes **both** more time and more clicks. @SouravGhosh